# Any way to silence Emacs keyboard shortcut advice?

Tags: emacs, elisp, dot-emacs, emacs24, minibuffer

Emacs sometimes can be rather annoying, it emits too much information in minibuffer. For instance, when I run `M-x gnus`, it tells me that

```
You can run `gnus' with <menu-bar><tools><gnus>
```

It also occurs when there is a keymap for certain command. I don't need them, But I don't know how to remove.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Actually I find them very useful.

Comment: @kindahero I can use `C-h f` to get the usage of a function, and it would tell me the keybings with it; Obviously it's easier to remember the keybings for some mode rather than the function name itself. If the keybings are rather complicated, I would try the `M-x` way. The suggestions just distract my attentions.

Comment: In particular, the menu suggestions are annouing and useless. I suppose one could define advice around the suggestion code to disable the menu bindings briefly during the time it looks for suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Customize the variable `suggest-key-bindings`: a value of `nil` will disable key binding suggestion.